# Updating several input fields when one of them changes its value

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I am building a web application in `php` (actually cakephp), `HTML5`, & `Jquery`.
In one page I have a form which will make too many calculations. In it there is a form with maybe 30 input fields. These fields are related to each other with formulas.

Whenever a field value changes, I want to update all others. How to achieve this?

Note: if there is some SDK which will help me in this, it will be better.

**Update 1**

I will make a short example: it is about designing some industrial product, let us call it a cabinet.

A cabinet consists of too many items, and these depend mainly on: **Width/Height/Depth + some additional characteristics (around 5)**. I need to calculate the specs of the components which constitute a cabinet. There are maybe 15 components. each component has a specific formula, and may depend on all mentioned inputs. If I change the width, many of the components specs should automatically update.

Comment: Are these relation between fields the same always? I mean, input1 is related to input2 by formula1 and input2 with input3 by formula1 too? Because if the formulas binding every input are different always, you're stuck with one by one coding. Please include example code to understand better.

Comment: Depending on its use, Have you considered performing the calculations server-side? This way, you can trigger an AJAX-submit and update the fields with the calculated results from the server. This *will* be slower than pure client side calculating, but may be more flexible; Depending on the exact nature of the calculations, the calculations may be part of your 'Model', in which case the entered values can be 'validated' at the same time (e.g. "Width cannot be a negative value")

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is, you need to use a generic selector:

```
$(".my_inputs")
```

Add an 'on()' EventHandler:

```
$(".my_inputs").on('change', function() { }
```

Then, within it, do whatever type of data manipulation you want:

```
$(".my_inputs").on('change', function() {
    // use jquery to repeat through all .my_inputs and alter their data
    // or set all .my_inputs to a specific value
    // or do anything else you want
}
```

Now that you have the general idea, look through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) to find details on however you'd like to manipulate the data (or just use good ole' Javascript! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is still a JS solution. Give each of the input boxes a class name (e.g. "myClass"), then you can do this:

```
$('#myInputfield').keyup(function(){
    $('.myClass').each(function(index){
        $(this).val($('#myInputfield').val());
    });
});
```

NOTE: You need JQuery to achieve this and it is assuming you are looking for changes in just one textbox (i.e. textbox with ID:myInputfield). The main textbox should not have the same class.